# Auto refresh a cached html

Tags: html, jsp

How can i auto refresh a cached html. i load a html submit and do some stuff and then close the browser and opens the browser which loads the cached html but it does not refresh..

Comment: Your question is unclear and needs more detail. What do you mean by "load a html submit"? What "stuff" are you doing? Is this even a programming question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *quite* sure on what you're getting at, but a cached HTML page is a snapshot of a page at a point in time. This means that if you are looking for an update from a webmaster or something like that by refreshing the page, you would be best to visit the actual page as a cached page doesn't change with the server's version of it.

Comment: Sorry about confusion. Please find steps below: